# Как вывести картинки в нескольких столбцах

Tags: python, matplotlib

Имеется вот такой вполне рабочий код:

```
for i in range(1,30):
  plt.imshow(print_df[i].reshape(8, 8), cmap="gray")
  plt.show()
```

который печатает подряд все картинки из дата сета.

Требуется напечатать эти картинки по 3 в ряд, то есть:

```
1 2 3
```

и так далее вниз

Answer (score 4):

Сетку из картинок формирует функция [`pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Во втором значении она возвращает двумерный массив объектов [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes). Именно эти объекты рисуют в `pyplot` всё, что тот умеет рисовать. Когда вы пользуетесь функциями из `pyplot` напрямую, они вызывают методы дефолтного объекта `Axes`. Ну а здесь вам надо вместо общих методов `pyplot` рисовать на конкретных чертежах.

```
_,axs = plt.subplots(10,3)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(3):
        ax = axs[i,j]
        cnt = (i*3+j)
        ax.imshow(print_df[cnt].reshape(8, 8), cmap="gray")
```

PS. *Axes* - это множественная форма слова *axis*, *ось*, а не *ax*, *топор*.
Pyplot таки рисует на осях, а не топорах ))

Answer (score 0):

Применил еще вот такую конструкцию:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(10, 3, figsize=(5, 10))
fig.subplots_adjust()
lbs = print_df.reshape(30, 8, 8)
for axi, img in zip(ax.flat, lbs):
    axi.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

Понятно, что она для частного примера, но вдруг кому пригодится.